# Wp admin ajax load more

Tags: ajax, query

can someone explain to me how to include load more for archive, custom post type? I’ve been looking all over internet for a way to use it but can’t seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not super fluent with javascript/jQuery or PHP.  if you're not looking to learn how to code then I would suggest you [pick a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/ajax+load+more/) to handle that for you.  Otherwise there's tons of tutorials out there on how to use ajax with wordpress to build that feature, [like this one](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/load-posts-ajax/).